# keeping an SSH connection alive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Here is a situation which I noticed.  I have a server to which I login via SSH and when I do it from **lan** then things work perfectly and I have noticed that even if the connection is idle (i.e. I am not doing any thing on SSH session just logged in) the connection is alive for a long time, but if I do an SSH on  same server from internet then the connection after some time dies.The server is a Ubuntu 10.04 server edition server.What can be possible reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable keepalives in your ssh client, your firewall/router is killing the idle connection.

I have `ServerAliveInterval 59` in `~/.ssh/config` for openssh client.

Comment: Ok I do not have any such line as you mentioned since the server is in a corporate data centre is it possible for the sysadmin to detect an idle connection in this situation given the fact that to this server I am the only person who has SSH access to it.

Comment: Just as clarification; consumer grade hardware with little memory kills connections that haven't been active for a while. TCP keepalives can cause disconnects, so you can also, if you use something like screen or tmux, put a clock in your status bar so you have trafic all the time :)

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the TCPKeepAlive option in [sshd_confi](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5)g on the server.  It looks like if this is enabled you will see more disconnections (which seems a bit counter intuitive until you read the doc) as any route changes between you and the server will result in a disconnection.  That is unlikely to happen on the LAN, but fairly likely across the internet.